# How to get geometry data of State/provinces Boundary Polygon(googleMap polygon) of Canada

Tags: gis

I want to apply the style to state boundary of Canada. I google but didn't get any geoJson or shapefile data of Canada state polygon boundary.
for example, implemented in [ArcGIS](https://extmapviewer.aer.ca/Onestop/Public/index.html) Alberta Province OutMost State Boundary.

Any help to get Canada States boundary/Polygon geometry data or link or WFS request url?

Comment: For open data, including spatial, I recommend asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for comment @PolyGeo but I got data so that I'm creating Answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following link of [Province and Territory Cartographic Boundary Files](https://open.canada.ca/data/dataset/bab06e04-e6d0-41f1-a595-6cff4d71bedf)

From there Access file and Parse through online tools like [MapSharper](http://mapshaper.org/) etc you can get geojson format data.